# Django multi-select widget?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

The Django admin site makes use of a really cool widget:

[image]

How can I make use of this widget in my own applications? I don't see anything like that [listed here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#ref-forms-widgets).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/):

> The Django Admin application defines a number of customized widgets for calendars, filtered selections, and so on. These widgets define media requirements, and the Django Admin uses the custom widgets in place of the Django defaults. The Admin templates will only include those media files that are required to render the widgets on any given page.
>
> If you like the widgets that the Django Admin application uses, feel free to use them in your own application! They’re all stored in django.contrib.admin.widgets.

In this case, you want the `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget. To use it, apply the widget on a form field like so:

```
my_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False))
```

Make sure to include the forms `media` in the template as it needs to include a few JS files.

Comment: Hrm... doesn't want to work for some reason. All the JS is there, but it isn't converting the selectbox for some reason. http://7src.com/~mnb2/a3/access

Comment: This is a wild guess but try setting your second argument (for the `is_stacked` variable) to False. Looking at the code, it looks like that may affect the display of two boxes or not. Unfortunately I can't test it myself right now so I'm just looking through code hehe :)

Comment: Nevermind. Found the problem. It needs `<script type="text/javascript" src="/~mnb2/a3/admin/jsi18n/"></script>` as well, which isn't included by `form.media`.

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that you need to be logged in as a superuser just to access that file!! I recommend saving the file out and including that instead.

Comment: @mpen, what exactly is located in `<script type="text/javascript" src="/~mnb2/a3/admin/jsi18n/"></script>`?  Any reason why it's not pointing to a specific `.js` file?

Comment: @NickBraunagel I wrote that like 8 years ago now. It does seem weird that that doesn't end with `.js`. I must have copied it off the Django admin site though.