# Django multiple select with JS

Tags: django, forms, django-admin, multiple-select

Can anyone tell me, how(if it's possible) can I make select with JavaScript such as autogenerated select in admin panel (using which we select user permissions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, see [another post about re-using the date widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form) but this will be too much trouble, you'd better try to use another widget which you will install, and so, know every dependencies and gotchas.

Here is another Multiselect for Django for example :
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2079/

...for this really cool jquery UI widget : http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

Comment: I found answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698435/django-multi-select-widget , sorry for my mistake. Widgets that you shown really nice, i'll try to use them too