# Trigger 'onchange' event when adding/removing options to a SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, select

I have a third-party js function that dynamically adds/removes options to a SELECT element and I would like to perform an action whenever options are changed.

I tried attaching an 'onchange' event to the select but the event is triggered only when changing 'selection', not 'options'.

Any hint on how I can do that?

Comment: What does that mean `only when changing 'selection', not 'options'.`

Comment: Does the third-party function provide a callback mechanism? Which plugin/function/whatever is ist?

Comment: @mplungjan: I was too short... I mean that 'onchange' is called when I change the selected option (by clicking on id and choosing another option); it is not called when the list of available options is changed by script.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I'm using Django FilteredSelectMultiple widget (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698435/django-multi-select-widget)

Comment: If you cannot attach an event to the adding, you will need to monitor the length of the select's options using setInterval for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to hack the 3rd party script to call your function when it adds/removes (or exchange the 3rd party script to a suitable jquery plugin).

Comment: I actually can do that, but I was wandering if there was an event-driven solution.