# Is it possible to use multiselect widget feature for a one-to-many model in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-widget

I am working on implementing features on Django Admin site, and I want to create a multiselect dropdown menu for a one-to-many model.

For example, like this: [Django multi-select widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698435/django-multi-select-widget)

But it looks like I can only use it for many-to-many models. Is there a workaround solution for this situation?