# Replacement for the default ManyToMany Widget of Forms

Tags: django

I know who to replace the ManyToMany Widget in the django admin interface:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('users',)
```

But how to replace the default widget in all views?

I guess this could be implemented without changing one line in my code or in django.

It would be great if I could the something like the Author part (two boxes for a ManyToMany input) in this picture with a widget:

[image]

I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click, but my users can't. They want an easier way.

Is there a way to replace all select-multiple widgets without many changes in my code?

Comment: override MultipleSelect widget class.

Comment: @AvinashRaj please elaborate "override MultipleSelect widget class."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do not understand your question, please clarify in the comments.

The [Django Form Widgets Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/) offers several pre-fab widgets that you can use to specify how a field in your form is rendered.

Without modifying the code in my views, I can simply add a `widget` keyword arg to the appropriate form fields.

forms.py (v1)

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (
    (1, "choice1"),
    (2, "choice2"),
    (3, "choice3"),
    )
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

This renders as a dropdown `select`:

```
<select id="id_field" name="field">
  <option value="1">choice1</option>
  <option value="2">choice2</option>
  <option value="3">choice3</option>
</select>
```

Now adding the `widget` keyword arg to my field:

forms.py (v2)

```
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

This renders as a list of checkboxes:

```
<ul id="id_field">
<li>
  <label for="id_field_0"><input id="id_field_0" name="field" type="checkbox" value="1" /> choice1</label>
</li>
<li>
  <label for="id_field_1"><input id="id_field_1" name="field" type="checkbox" value="2" /> choice2</label>
</li>
<li>
  <label for="id_field_2"><input id="id_field_2" name="field" type="checkbox" value="3" /> choice3</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

### Edit

It is also possible to add widgets that are used by Django Admin. See [Django multi-select widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698435/django-multi-select-widget) for more information about this. Simply import the appropriate widget:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
```

and use that instead. Note that in this particular case you will also need to include the form's `media` to get the desired effect.

Comment: Yes, CheckboxSelectMultiple is nice and much more usable than ctrl-click of the default widget. Is there a way to get something like the two nice boxes in the admin to move entries left and right way a widget? I added a image to the question to.

Comment: @guettli you can add some css and js on top, to make it even better, for example https://github.com/lou/multi-select

Comment: @guettli do you have follow-up q's to this answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a base class which ovride `formfield_for_manytomany`

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class ManyToManyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['widget']= widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
            db_field.verbose_name,
            db_field.name in self.filter_vertical
        )

        return super(admin.ModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
            db_field, request=request, **kwargs)

class SomeModelAdmin(ManyToManyAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace default widgets in django forms.

This works for me:

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
    # replace MultipleChoise in Forms
    forms.MultipleChoiceField.widget = FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False)
    # replace MultipleChoise in ModelForms
    forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField.widget = FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False)
```

1. Add code above to file `forms_setup.py` in your main project
2. Then in `settings.py` import file `forms_setup.py`:

   ```
   from .forms_setup import *
   ```

Comment: Overwrites at module level ... I think it is called monkey patching ... yes, this could work if you are lucky. Code which was executed before those lines are not reached with this patching ...