# How to use a form showing selected and not selected in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

In django admin the Groups element of the Change User form gives you two lists with arrows to move from one list to the other.  Something like the attached.
[image]

I have a many to many field where I would like Django Admin to use this form but I cannot find out how to use it.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I thought it was used by default for all M2M relations in the admin. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698435/django-multi-select-widget can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) option in your ModelAdmin class.